# How to mix dynamically updating messages inside static messages in SQLite coming from MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sqlite, synchronization

We have a message type (the one you see with the loader) that is supposed to have dynamic update capability. As more jobs are added to the related job on the MongoDB collection, this bot UX will display and represent the updates with thumbnails up to the first 3 of a particular job. Each job has a dynamic msg doing this. Then when you tap the message the rest will load on a fetch() from MongoDB. But we use SQLite locally and the messages that might often surround this type of message, and that are more static in nature, are fetched from MongoDB and stored in local storage in SQLite so when user opens bot it's a fast open. It is ok for us to async fetch the dynamic message state direct from MongoDB after the reset of the SQlite and static messages load, but we keeping the dynamic messages in sync and correctly positioned in-line is a challenge. How would this best be approached?

[image]